Mocking TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep() with Mockito
I want to test a method in Java 17 (springboot 3.x, Mockito 5.x) and i'm currently using mockito.
This method looks like this :
public int test(){
    try {
        var test = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS;
        test.sleep(500L);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;

}

I want my TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500L) to throw an InterruptedException and thus the method will return 1.
I tried many things, like this :
try(var staticMock = Mockito.mockStatic(TimeUnit.class)) {
        var mock = Mockito.mock(TimeUnit.class);
        staticMock.when(() -> mock.sleep(anyLong())).thenThrow(new InterruptedException());
    }

I also tried this :
try(var staticMock = Mockito.mockStatic(TimeUnit.class)) {

        var mock = Mockito.mock(TimeUnit.class);
        doThrow(InterruptedException.class).when(mock).sleep(anyLong());
        staticMock.when(TimeUnit::values).thenReturn(new TimeUnit[]{mock});
    }

But it won't work either -> each time the method returns 0 or there is a mockito error.
I want to specify something : I don't want to make a specific class containing TimeUnit just for testing this case. I personnaly think this is a bad pratice as it makes the code less readable for anyone not familiar with the project. And besides, understanding how to work with this case will help me also understand more Mockito (this also works if this is not possible).
Is there a way to do this just with Mockito ?

var test = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS; will be a specific instance of TimeUnit and there's no way to inject a mock here unless you're changing the bytecode. Why don't you try to run this code in another thread and interrupt that one from your test?

What do you mean by that?
Something like that?
AtomicInteger ret = new AtomicInteger();
    var thread = new Thread(() -> {
        ret.set(paymentManagerService.test());
    });
    thread.start();
    thread.interrupt();

    assertEquals(1, ret.get());


You could abstract TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS into a class e.g. TimeOperations which you pass into your code and use a mocked version in your test

TimeUnit.sleep() IS NOT A STATIC METHOD. TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS is a static field.

Try mocking Thread.sleep. TimeUnit.sleep documents that it uses this method: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/23/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#sleep(long)

@Jaybird I don't want to abstract class just for testing purposes. I know this is common, but I find it ugly to bend the production code just for a test.

@lance-java Yes I know, but i showed what I tried in desperation. If you have a solution, i'll be happy though.

@RobSpoor That is a neat answer, thank you. I just tried it but no luck, Mockito does not allow mocking static methods of java.lang.Thread or java.lang.System...

I suggest using Thread.sleep(...) instead of TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(...) which will be easier to mock since there's no static fields involved.

Instead of mocking interruption you can actually interrupt the thread. You need to do that from a different thread, but that's easily done using a ScheduledExecutorService:
try (ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()) {
    Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();

    executor.schedule(thread::interrupt, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    assertThrows(InterruptedException.class, () -> TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2));
}


Thank you! Solutions closest to reality are often the best one! This perfectly works !

You're welcome :)

I suggest creating a service for sleeping. You can then inject this service where required, and mock it during testing
public class Sleeper {
   public void sleep(int millis) throws InterruptedException {
      TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(millis);
   }
}


Thank you for your answer. As I said in my question, I don't want to make a class wrapping this because it introduces a layer of abstraction that is not necessary for the production code and I try to stay as standard as possible for any newcomer joining to code.

Perhaps you could use Thread.sleep(...) instead of TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(...) which is easier to mock since there's no static fields involved

Sadly you cannot mock Thread or System class, mockito prevents it
